# Unable to get text from ace.js-div in express.js

Tags: javascript, express, request, handlebars.js, ace-editor

I'm using ace.js(https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) to create a snippet-editor. The html looks like this:

```
<div id="editor" name="editor">{{ text }}</div>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.3/ace.js"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
</script>
```

When I've changed the text, I would like to save to a mongoose-db. But I'm not able to get the text from the editor in my post-request. How do I get the text from the div when I call the save-request?

```
router.route("/home/save/:id")
    .post(function(request, response) {
        console.log(request.body.editor) // -> undefined
        console.log(request.body) // -> {}

    });
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder edited the question a bit. Hope it's more understandable! I want to get the code the same way you get it through a form when for example logging in, but I do not want to put the text in an input. Maybe I could place the div in a form with an action?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Solved it, sorry for the fussy question, had a hard time explaining it well hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the perhaps fussy question. Had a hard time explaining the problem. But if anyone for some reason get in the same situation, I solved it by making a kind of a lazy solution.

I took inspiration from https://jsfiddle.net/deepumohanp/tGF6y/ and got the text from the ace-div and placed it in an input. Then I just got the input from the next request:

```
{{> nav }}

<div id="editor">{{ text }}</div>

<form action="/home/save/{{ this.sessionId }}" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="" name="content" id="content">
    <button>Save</button>
</form>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.3/ace.js"></script>
<script>
    var textarea = document.querySelector("#content");

    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

    console.log(textarea.value);
    console.log(editor.getSession().getValue());

    editor.getSession().on("change", function () {
        textarea.value = editor.getSession().getValue();
    });

    textarea.value = editor.getSession().getValue();
</script>
```

That way, the request.body.content returned with the text:

```
router.route("/home/save/:id")
    .post(function(request, response) {
        console.log(request.body.content) // -> text

    });
```

Comment: Thanks, only `input.value` has no carriage returns at all - replaced `<input>` to `<textarea>`. Works fine!